# How do I take operands as registers from the byte value?

Tags: emulation, z80

I have a fairly simple program so far to start off my emulation experience. I load in an instruction and determine how many (if any) operands there are, then I grab those operands and use them. For things like jumps and pushes it's somewhat straightforward until I get to registers.. How do I know when an operand is a register? Or how can I tell if it's the **value** at an address instead of just an address (i.e when they use something like `ld (hl),a`)

I'm rather new to emulation and all, but I have a decent bit of experience with assembly, even for the z80.

### Question

How do I tell the difference between what is meant as a register and what is meant as an address or dereference of an address?

Comment: You should drop by on omnimaga.org when you get to tricky parts of emulation, like computing the flags and emulating daa, or worst of all, emulating peripherals. Plenty of z80 experts there, and many emulator writers

Comment: @harold Thanks! Ive actually learned a ton since making this post. I successfully made a Chip-8 emulator in Javascript and now Im in the process of casing through all of z80 opcodes. Im sure ill be checking out omnimaga as i do interrupts, though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you decode the instruction. For example in `ld (hl), a`, which is 0x77, or 0b01110111, the first 01 tell you it's an `ld reg8, reg8` and that you have to decode two groups of 3 bits, each a reg8. So 110 and 111, and you look them up in the reg8 decoding table, where 110 means `(hl)` and 111 means `a`. Alternatively you could just make a Giant Switch of Death and directly decode 0x77 to `ld (hl), a`, but that's more of a difference in implementation than anything deep or significant.

The instruction completely specifies what the operands are, so this "how do I tell" question strikes me as a bit silly - the answer is already staring you right in the face when you're decoding the instruction.

See also: [decoding z80 opcodes](http://www.z80.info/decoding.htm)

Comment: I was not aware that the opcodes held that :) so is each instruction one byte including operands?

Comment: @ChristopherWirt there are also prefixes and for some instructions you have to read additional bytes for immediate arguments or index-displacement. The prefixes (if any) combined with the main opcode will tell you how many extra bytes to read and what they mean. For example for both 21 and 2A you read two extra bytes and load something into `hl`, for 21 it's those immediate bytes, for 2A it's the value from RAM at the address given by those immediate bytes (and one past that address, because it's a 16bit load obviously).

Comment: Yeah ive got that much. Great, this is very very helpful. Thanks!